In which episode do all Marvel heroes team up to fight Galactus?
I am trying to identify a crossover episode from some 90's Marvel animated series where Galactus comes to earth because he is becoming weak and needs to feed and one of his heralds is creating trouble. 
The Marvel heroes fighting with him which I am sure of are Fantastic Four, Nova, Silver Surfer, Ghost Rider and might be many more. Specially Ghost Rider uses his catchy line to Galactus as 'look into my eyes'. 
I think it's a more then one episode event but not sure. There is slight possibility that I have seen Spider-Man fighting Silver Surfer and some X-Men too but not sure. In the end Nova saves Galactus and becomes his new herald.


In the episode, When Calls Galactus, Terrax attacks Earth (Manhattan). Galactus isn't terribly pleased to learn that his herald has defected, so he comes back to Earth to do away with Terrax. One problem, Galactus needs to feed, and the only planet in the vicinity is Earth! Since Galactus no longer has a herald to search out planets for him, he attempts to devour Earth. Thor and Ghost Rider arrive on the scene, but their efforts are useless. As a result, Frankie Raye offers to become Nova, Galactus' new herald. Galactus makes two more cameo appearances in Fantastic Four, one being in Hopelessly Impossible and another in Doomsday. - Galactus - Marvel Animated Universe Wiki

When Calls Galactus is from Fantastic Four (1994 TV series).
Video on youtube
IMDb Link - Fantastic Four: Season 2, Episode 8

When Calls Galactus looks the right one but will accept it after watching it.

added links where you can watch the video and view more info on the series

Interesting. In the original John Byrne comic, the Avengers and Dr. Strange help out while Daredevil and Spider-Man just watch. They actually almost kill him. Richards saves him which makes Lilandra pretty mad. Ironically, in another story it is established that killing Galactus ends the universe, so Reed unknowingly saved everything.
